# Extjs 4.1.1a Check symbol of Checkbox on grid panel doesn't work

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

on a tab panel I create a tab for each year I have in a database (in this case the database contains at the moment only 3 years: 2012, 2013 ans 2014) and finally I set as active tab the current year (2013). In the controller I do the following:

```
var tp= this.getTpOverview();

this.getPlannedYearsStore().load({
    callback: function(records) {           
        for (i=0; i< records.length; i++){
            var year = records[i].data.year;

            var tab = tp.add({
            title: year,
            year: year,
            layout:'fit',
            listeners: {
                activate: function() {
                    var tbOverview = Ext.getCmp('tabOverview-'+ this.year);
                        if (!tbOverview) {
                            var gridOverview = Ext.create('WLPT.view.CPAssMonthActHours', {
                                id: 'tabOverview-' + this.year,
                                year: this.year,
                                xtype: 'cpassmonthacthoursview',
                                autoScroll: true
                            });
                            this.add(gridOverview);                                    
                        } else {
                            selectedYear = this.year;
                            tbOverview.getStore().load({
                                params : {
                                    wrk_year: selectedYear
                                }
                            });
                        }                                
                    }                            
                }
            });
            if (currentYear == parseInt(records[i].data.year)) {
                tab2Activate = tab;
            }
        }
        tp.setActiveTab(tab2Activate);
    }
});
```

When I run the application this seams to work fine.

I forgot to say that **each tab** contains a **grid panel** with a **check column** (Checkbox model) and for each item (row) a cell editor is setted on selected cells.

The active tab (2013) works fine. I can check the checkboxes to perfom a sum of the selected items. Indeed, the cell editor works fine.

The problem appears when I change the tab. The corresponding grid comes with the checkbox column. But on the javascript console appears the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setWidth' of undefined ext-all-debug.js:95689
Ext.define.onColumnResize ext-all-debug.js:95689
Ext.define.onColumnResize ext-all-debug.js:101362
Ext.util.Event.Ext.extend.fire ext-all-debug.js:8896
Ext.define.continueFireEvent ext-all-debug.js:9102
Ext.define.fireEvent ext-all-debug.js:9080
Ext.override.fireEvent ext-all-debug.js:51104
Ext.define.onHeaderResize ext-all-debug.js:97344
Ext.define.afterComponentLayout ext-all-debug.js:98063
Ext.define.notifyOwner ext-all-debug.js:28381
Ext.define.callLayout ext-all-debug.js:103511
Ext.define.flushLayouts ext-all-debug.js:103680
Ext.define.runComplete ext-all-debug.js:104194
callOverrideParent ext-all-debug.js:54
Base.implement.callParent ext-all-debug.js:3813
Ext.override.runComplete ext-all-debug.js:21234
Ext.define.run ext-all-debug.js:104175
Ext.define.statics.flushLayouts ext-all-debug.js:21238
Ext.define.statics.resumeLayouts ext-all-debug.js:21246
Ext.resumeLayouts ext-all-debug.js:23343
Ext.define.setActiveTab ext-all-debug.js:111589
Ext.define.onClick ext-all-debug.js:111357
(anonymous function)
Ext.apply.createListenerWrap.wrap
```

Despite that, the grid is shown correctly. But, when I select a item the javascript console shows the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'up' of null ext-all-debug.js:99591
Ext.define.onRowFocus ext-all-debug.js:99591
Ext.util.Event.Ext.extend.fire ext-all-debug.js:8896
Ext.define.continueFireEvent ext-all-debug.js:9102
Ext.define.fireEvent ext-all-debug.js:9080
Ext.override.fireEvent ext-all-debug.js:51104
Ext.define.focusRow ext-all-debug.js:92462
Ext.define.onRowFocus ext-all-debug.js:92423
Ext.define.onLastFocusChanged ext-all-debug.js:109495
Ext.define.setLastFocused ext-all-debug.js:83855
Ext.define.doMultiSelect ext-all-debug.js:83761
Ext.define.doSelect ext-all-debug.js:83721
Ext.define.selectWithEvent ext-all-debug.js:83623
Ext.define.onRowMouseDown ext-all-debug.js:109750
Ext.util.Event.Ext.extend.fire ext-all-debug.js:8896
Ext.define.continueFireEvent ext-all-debug.js:9102
Ext.define.fireEvent ext-all-debug.js:9080
Ext.override.fireEvent ext-all-debug.js:51104
Ext.define.processUIEvent ext-all-debug.js:85315
Ext.define.handleEvent ext-all-debug.js:85227
(anonymous function)
Ext.apply.createListenerWrap.wrap
```

The selection on the item fires the event 'select' and 'deselect' when I click a second time. But the    check symbol on the checkbox doesn't work any time.

I have thougth to put this symbol manually on the events 'select' and 'deselect' as a workaround, but I don't know how to put this style and which one is.

Do you have any ideas? Look forward for your suggestions. Thank you in advance.
Manuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the errors are not related to the code you posted. In fact, your code does not set the width, nor does it call `up`.

I find your code convoluted: a callback with a listener inside, that creates a view inside. And I don't understand if your code is inside a controller or another class.

Here is a problem:

```
var tab = tp.add({
//xtype  is missing
title: year,
```

For debugging, I can giv you the following recommendation:

- Use `ext-dev.js` instead of `ext-all-debug.js`. This will load all required classes one after the other, and the errors in the backtrace are not all inside `ext-all-debug.js`, but each line shows the line in the source class with all comments in it.

To get a cleaner programming style, try to follow the MVC pattern strictly:

- Folder structure as [recommended](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/application_architecture)
- Define events in the controller, like

  ```
  init: function(){
      this.listen({
          store: {
              '#plannedYearsStore': {load: this.onPlannedYearsStoreLoad}
          }
      })
      this.control({
          'tab': {activate: this.onTabActivate}
      })
  },
  onPlannedYearsStoreLoad: function (store, records){
      for (i=0; i< records.length; i++){
          var year = records[i].data.year;
          var tab = tp.add({
      ...
  },
  onTabActivate: function (){
      var tbOverview = Ext.getCmp('tabOverview-'+ this.year);
      ...
  },
  ```
- If possible, define your tab in a view class in a separate file.

When you adhere striclty to this MVC structure, you will get a much easier maintainable code.

Comment: Thank you Lorenz for your advice. Indeed, I follow the MVC structur and the conde is in the controller. Only in this complex case it is a little messy. I'll try to use ext-dev.js. Manuel